# I think I missed something in 'It Follows'

Tags: plot-explanation, it-follows

There is a scene in *It Follows* where Jay drives to the sea and looks at 3 men in a boat.  She enters the water and, in the next scene, is crying as she drives home.  I assumed she had swum out and had a sexual encounter with them but the rest of the film would imply this is not the case.

So was she just crying with frustration about not being able to go through with it?

What was the actual point of the scene?

Her ex-boyfriend explained that if it killed her it would then work it's way back through the line.  However, he got targeted after a one night stand so how did he know this?  How does anyone know it would keep going all the way back to patient zero, if had ever done this then wouldn't everyone involved be dead?

Was the girl from the opening scene the girl in the picture with him?

Is it explained why, rather than waste time seducing Jay, he didn't just take a trip to Brazil or somewhere far away and sleep with a prostitute?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. You should break them down into separate questions.

Comment: And / or maybe the movie just has a lot of problems.

Comment: @What really makes you think that she didn't have sex with the three boat guys? I just thought they got killed by It pretty quickly, so It came back for her.

Comment: This question seems to ask quite a few completely unrelated questions. There's the main question about the three boat guys (to which the whole *"how do they know it goes to the next guy"* question might be related, too). And then there's the rather unrelated question about the girl in the picture and Brazil question. You might want to concentrate on the main question (and maybe ask the other ones as separate questions). Related meta discussion: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2001/49.

Answer (score 6):

*My personal interpretation*

**Her ex-boyfriend explained that if it killed her it would then work it's way back through the line. However, he got targeted after a one night stand so how did he know this? How does anyone know it would keep going all the way back to patient zero, if had ever done this then wouldn't everyone involved be dead?**

Hugh / Jeff has a one night stand with some random lady at the bar and he starts seeing them. Although, he doesn't see them after having intercourse with his girlfriend (Annie), the very same girl who dies at the beginning of the movie.

The reason for him to go to a different place and starts dating Jay is unknown, may be his girlfriend starts seeing them and he decided to stay away from her and the place until everything settles down, came to a different place and started dating Jay.

Guessing game at the theater, a pivotal scene where Hugh points at some girl but Jay can't see her, it again started following him at the theater and at the restaurant. Meaning, the previous night Annie (his ex) died (starting scene) and it started following him. This is where he formed the theory that he could pass it to someone else by intercourse and it comes back if the person, who's been passed dies.

**Is it explained why, rather than waste time seducing Jay, he didn't just take a trip to Brazil or somewhere far away and sleep with a prostitute?**

(continuation) Now he has to pass it to someone else to keep himself safe, so, he passes it to Jay. (Please don't be mad, I know he could have done the same thing to some random prostitute but may be he thought it's not safe to do it with a prostitute without condom :). Also he suggests Jay in the later scene to pass it on by sleeping also tells that it's easy for her, she's a girl and anyone would sleep with her.).

**Was the girl from the opening scene the girl in the picture with him?**

Yes, it's the same brunette, it's the only connection (in the entire movie) between the girl in the opening scene and the one in the picture.

**Intercourse with 3 men on a boat, What was the actual point of the scene?**

After that scene, when Paul meets her, she says, "It's gonna be here sooner or later.". She had intercourse with the three guys on the boat and while returning home she cries because knowingly she passed it on to innocent guys.

Answer (score 3):

I think she definitely did have sex with the guys. When she got home she said that she "bought some time" which means she was expecting those guys to die, but at least she'd have a couple days to think.

Answer (score 0):

I think he would feel too guilty giving it to a random hooker. He wanted someone who he could fill in with what he knew about the haunting so she'd at least have a fighting chance.

I do believe the girl in the picture was from the beginning and it's possible that she was crying because maybe she was gang-banged on the boat.

I'm not entirely sure, as the ending was tricky for me to fully understand.

Comment: If she had had sex with the guys on the boat then the ... whatever it was would have chased them rather than her, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Stefan And it did, but since they had no idea what it was about, they got killed pretty quickly. And then it came back to her.

Answer (score 0):

My theory was that she did probably go through with the sex with the 3 guys because it shows that her cast was slightly torn but like Jake did in the beginning, he warned her about the people walking towards them and they probably were not warned and probably died. The point of that scene and the scene with the hookers is that they had the option to give it to anyone but it would be on their conscience. The girl was probably from the bar and he possibly could've heard about it on the news. You have to remember all the people walking were all related to them somehow.

Answer (score -2):

of course she had sex with at least two of the guys on the boat because the evil often times shows up as the prior victims stalking the "passed to" person.  So in the pool scene you see one guy throwing the tv at the pool that is one of the guys on the boat.  The scene before it when they drive away to the big swimming gym, there is an old guy standing on top of the house, and he is another guy from that boat... hope this helps.  i mean obviously you recognize the girl who died at the beginning of the movie shows up as one of the evil possessed walker in the middle of the movie.

Comment: There is nothing to indicate that the monster must kill someone in order to take their form; in fact, we are told that it can take the form of people that the victim knows, and we see it take the form both of Jay's father and Greg's mother.